# isnumber formula to pull in certain values when number exists, other values when a text string exists?

Tags: excel

I have a formula I'm using to extract the MID of a value in between two `-` delimiters, and it does well with that. Sometimes, a number doesn't exist in between, but instead a two character text string.

`=AN7&" (Z"&RIGHT(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(AK7,"-",REPT(" ",LEN(AK7))),LEN(SUBSTITUTE(AK7,"-",REPT(" ",LEN(AK7))))-LEN(AK7)*2,LEN(AK7)))*1)&")"`

How could I update this formula to account for those occurrences? I figure wrapping an `IF(ISNUMBER....FORMULA),.....` type statement would work, but I can't quite figure it out.

if a number exists, it works, but if a `CA` or `UK` comes up, I get a value error. I want it to not have the `" (Z"` part when those text strings come up and to just put in the two letter text string.

Hope this makes sense

Comment: Some example inputs with expected outputs would help. What did you try with `IF()`? It sounds like it should be straight-forward.

Comment: I tried this: `=IF(ISNUMBER(AN7&" (Z"&RIGHT(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(AK7,"-",REPT(" ",LEN(AK7))),LEN(SUBSTITUTE(AK7,"-",REPT(" ",LEN(AK7))))-LEN(AK7)*2,LEN(AK7)))*1)&")"),AN7&" "&MID(LEFT(AK7,FIND("-",AK7)-1),FIND("-",AK7)+1,LEN(AK7)))` but it's just giving me a `FALSE` return

Comment: In `=IF(ISNUMBER(AN7&" (Z" ...` you seem to be testing if a string which contains the literal text `" (Z"` is a number. Obviously it can't be. You need to think more carefully about what you want to feed `ISNUMBER()`

Comment: @JohnColeman would I be putting the `RIGHT(TRIM(....` part in between the `IF` and `ISNUMBER` part?

Comment: Probably. Whatever part of the expression is sometimes a number and sometimes something else is what you should be testing.